# Flutter how to check if a debugger is attached to the application

Tags: android, flutter, application-security

Security team wants me to use preventive techniques to prevent the debugger from connecting to the application.

For Android, it can be done using the **isDebuggerConnected** method of the **android.os.Debug** class.

For iOS, the use of PT_DENY_ATTACH can be implemented, which ensures that no debugger can be attached to the process called ”ptrace”.

The purpose is to terminate the application in case it is detected if there is a debugger attached to the application.

What I have tried, and I'm not really sure if its the right way to do it, is the following:

At least for Android, in the MainActivity file:

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import android.os.Debug
import android.util.Log

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.i("Kotlin lifeCycle", "onResume")
        val isBeingDebugged: Boolean = android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected()
        Log.i("Kotlin lifeCycle onResume", "isBeingDebugged: " + isBeingDebugged)
    }
}
```

however I always get: isBeingDebugged: false

I have tried onCreate, onResume, lifecycle methods but these don't always get executed.

Is there a way to use this "android.os.Debug" class and its methods inside the Dart classes to do this check in a more controlled way?